# Access the errors in Laravel

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5

I have the following function for a route named `/home`:

```
public function home(){
  if(Session::has("user_id")){
        return view("home");
    }else{
        return view("welcome", [
            'error_message' => "Please log in to access that page!"
        ]);
    }
}
```

Then, in my `welcome` view, I show the error like this:

```
<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
<p> {{ $error_message }} </p>
</div>
```

Everything works as expected but the error keeps on showing when I refresh the page again and again. I know that the variable hasn't been `unset` so it is happening. But, the real question is:

> Can't I do the same using MessageBag instance of Laravel?

During form validation, if error occurs, then the error gets showed up and if I refresh the page its get vanished. So, can't I bring the same behavior in my page using the method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Example 1**

To set error use

```
return redirect()->back()->withErrors('my message');
```

To access errors in blade use

```
@if ($errors->any())
<div class="alert alert-danger">
    <ul class="mb-0">
        @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
            <li>{!! $error !!}</li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
</div>
@endif
```

And yes, use redirect instead of returning different views on the same route, because it is more clear.

**Example 2**
But if you want to learn it hard way, set alerts like so

```
session()->flash('alert', 'your message');
```

and access it like so

```
<div class="alert alert-success"> {{ session('alert') }}</div>
```

**Example 3**

if you want to use a MessageBag all you need is throw a special exception

```
throw ValidationException::withMessages([
            'message' => ['my message here'],
        ])->status(400);
```

and access it as it is shown in example-1

Comment: Thank you! That was what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
public function home(){
    if(Session::has("user_id")){
       return view("home");
    }else{
       return view("welcome")->with('error_message', 'Please log in to access the page');
    }
}
```

and

```
@if(!empty($error_message))
  <div class="alert alert-success"> {{ $error_message }}</div>
@endif
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes it is one unclear question, I also noticed the same problem as you are solving with your answer, but then I read further and it turns out that the member wants to use a MessageBag. :)